# Visual Studio Installer Project - Create a folder in the install directory

Tags: installation, project

I am trying to create a installer project, so that when it installs, I want the installer to create a folder called "App_Data" in the installation folder. Basically, this is a winforms application and I have log4net configured to write the logs in this folder called "App_Data" in the executing assembly's parent folder. I have tried options like Installation Project --> File System --> Create Custom Folder as some people advice but when I run the installation I don't see the folder created on the Install location. Has anybody faced a requirement like this?
Thanks,
Venky

Comment: Is your installation project of type InstallShield?

Comment: Mine is a Visual Studio Installer --> Setup project

Answer (score 1):

If your installation project is of type InstallShield, try this:

Go to the Project Assistant file under your project in solution explorer
[image: Project Assinstant]

Then, click in Application Files

[image: Application files]

After that, click in "Add folders" button at right bottom of screen

[image: Add folders]

and select your folder.

You must create the folder that you need in your pc, and then select it from "Add folders" button.
If you want some files inside this folder, put it before add the folder in project.

Hope helps.

Comment: Mine is a Visual studio installer .. Not a installsheild installer